# How to add this array to MySQL (very confused)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have been trying to find answer to this question for a while but I was not able to...
So I have to ask a question...

To make it short, I will not post any code that I have but ask straight forward question.

I have array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ID09666
            [1] => ID14366
            [2] => ID8174
            [3] => ID4106
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /title_is_fantastic/
            [1] => /what_an_awesome_title/
            [2] => /great_title/
            [3] => /awesome_title/
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title is fantastic
            [1] => What an awesome title
            [2] => Great title
            [3] => Awesome title
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100%
            [1] => 86%
            [2] => 76%
            [3] => 68%
        )

)
```

Values that I need to add to DB are:

```
ID = ID09666
url = /title_is_fantastic/
title = Title is fantastic
percent = 100%
```

So how can I add those values fastest to the database?
I have got very confused with this array so any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I understand your point. The problem is that your orginal array is somewhat quite awards. If I was you, I would make a function to rearrange the array first to the form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => ID09666
            [url] => /title_is_fantastic/
            [title] => Title is fantastic
            [percent] => 100%
        )
     ...
)
```

Then access to the first (or any) element is straight forward.
THe function is something like:

```
function rearrange($arr){
    $array_number = count($arr[0]);
    $new_arr = array();
    for ($i=0,$i<$array_number<$i++){
       $new_arr[$i]['id']=$arr[0][$i];
       $new_arr[$i]['url']=$arr[1][$i];
       $new_arr[$i]['title']=$arr[2][$i];
       $new_arr[$i]['percent']=$arr[3][$i];
    }
    return $new_arr;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly my thought as well, I was thinking how to rearrange array and it would be quite easier to handle it, so that's just one more thing that I have just learned today. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array is `$array`:

```
$length = count($array[0]);
$rows = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
     $rows[] = "(".array($array[0][$i].", ".$array[1][$i].", ".$array[2][$i].", ".$array[3][$i].")";

// Ugly language with no executemany function... So we build a INSERT INTO with many values by ourselves 
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, url, title, percent) VALUES " . implode(',', $rows);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
try {
    $stmt->execute($insert_values);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for! Thank you! :)